# Eclipse JUnit H2 CSV input. Copy CSV-files to target

Tags: eclipse, junit4, h2

I use Eclipse/ Maven, Weblogic, Oracle DB. For JUnit tests I use OpenEJB, H2. I import table data from CSV-files (CSVREAD) located in:
...\\src\test\resources\h2\test_data\\
Then the data is exclusive to the test method.
When I build the project, the CSV-files are copied to the target folder. That is OK. But If I only change a CSV-file and run the test again, the changed CSV-file is not copied to the target folder. I have to do the copy manually. Is there a way of setting it up, so the changed CSV-files are copied automatic to target, when I run the test again?

Comment: Eclipse would need to 'know' that the file is changed. Do you change the file within in Eclipse, or refresh the file list in Eclipse?

Comment: Sorry, it is so simple as refresh the file list in Eclipse.

Comment: OK, I added this as the answer (just for completeness).

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing the file list in Eclipse after file is modified should be sufficient.